# Координаты точки на окружности без тригонометрии

Tags: алгоритм, математика

Как найти координаты точки на окружности, зная координаты центра окружности, радиус и угол между горизонтальной осью и диаметром, проходящим через искомую точку, не используя тригонометрические функции?

Comment: А угол "между горизонтальной осью и диаметром" у вас в чем задан, в градусах или вектором или еще как-то?

Comment: @KromStern, скорее всего, необходимо перевести полярные координаты в декартовые. Так что в градусах.

Comment: @Arhad: Хотелось бы услышать точные условия от автора. Мы можем только предполагать ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По-моему, никак. Разве что считать тригонометрию разложением в ряд Тейлора. Просто раз задан именно угол, а не, скажем, его тангенс или еще что-то в этом духе — тогда можно было бы выполнять соответствующие преобразования из одних функций в другие.

Если не секрет — с чем связано такое ограничение?

Answer (score 2):

Если надо просто избавиться от явного вызова sin, cos и т.п., то берите формулы с тригонометрическими функциями, а потом просто замените sin на какой-нибудь алгоритм приближенного вычисления:

1. Интерполяция по таблице
2. [CORDIC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORDIC)
3. Ряд Тейлора